# License Gradle Plugin

Tags: groovy, gradle

How can we search, skip and write for required header(License) in .groovy, .java, .jsp, .txt files which are exist in src directory using gradle script.

How can we install License Plugin?

Answer (score 3):

You mean [this license plugin](https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin)?

The instructions seem pretty clear (copied here from the link above):

> In your build.gradle file add:
>
> ```
> buildscript {
>     repositories {
>         mavenCentral()
>     }
>
>     dependencies {
>         classpath 'nl.javadude.gradle.plugins:license-gradle-plugin:0.5.0'
>     }
> }
>
> apply plugin: 'license'
> ```